# Send bulk emails with valid DMARC security

Tags: email, email-bounces, dmarc, bulk

We are implementing a feedback feature in our web application. After completion of an event, we are sending emails requesting feedback and ratings to our visitors.

If we do write the following DMARC entry, it is not working. If we make DMARC changes, it works, but DMARC validation fails for our domain.

Not working when -

`v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:test@mydomain.com`

Working when -

`v=DMARC1; p=none; rua=mailto:test@mydomain.com`

We also need to ensure the Security of our domain along with valid DMARC policy.

Is there any way to send bulk emails along with valid DMARC security?

Comment: The validation always fails, the failure is just ignored with the second configuration. Find out why it fails. Check the headers of the mails, the responses, the SPF configuration, DKIM etc.

Comment: *If we do write the following DMARC entry, it is not working. If we make DMARC changes, it works* - what is the **it** you're referring to? The email fails to send? That's a clue that you don't have something set up correctly, most likely your SPF record.

Comment: with this DMARC settings bulk email notification is not working 
` v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:akashs@first-insight.com`

Comment: Send one such message somewhere it is both accepted and checked, and then view what that recipient said about its SPF and DKIM status. If you do not know how to do that, follow the instructions of a page like https://www.mail-tester.com/ and report then [edit] your question to quote how they received the message.